# Pattern match any member of a Context

Tags: pattern-matching

Let's say I have four functions: `x`, `y`, `` X`x ``, and `` X`y ``. Writing a pattern that matches `x`, but not `` X`x `` is easy

```
f[_x] := True; f[_] := False
{ f[x[]], f[X`x[]] }
(* {True, False} *)
```

and the reverse is also straightforward

```
g[_X`x] := True; g[_] := False
{ g[x[]], g[X`x[]] }
(* {False, True} *)
```

But, how would I match all members of `` X` ``?

Obviously, this works

```
h[_?(MemberQ[Names["X`*"], ToString@Head@#] &)] := True
h[_] := False
{ h[x[]], h[X`x[]], h[X`y[]] }
(* {False, True, True} *)
```

but it seems excessive, especially if the `Context` contains a large number of functions.

Answer (score 7):

How about this?

```
m[x_Symbol[___] /; Context[x] === "X`"] := True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not as simple as I would like, but it seems like it is less computationally complex than the `Names` method, above.

```
m[_?(Context @@ {Head@#} == "X`" &)] := True
m[_] := False
{ m[x[]], m[X`x[]], m[X`y[]] }
(* {False, True, True} *)
```

Unfortunately, `Context` has a `HoldFirst` attribute, so I used `Apply` (`@@`) to get around it. It could have just as easily been done using `With`.

Comment: Wait a minute, why can't you use ``_?(Context @@ # == "X`" &)`` ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `Context` expects a symbol or string, so ``Context[X`x[]]`` generates an error.

Comment: Why would it see that in your example?  How else are you using this pattern?

Comment: I don't think I understand your requirements so I've lifted my vote for the time being.  I cannot figure out what you're actually trying to match.  It seems to me that something like ``a_Symbol[___] /; Context[a] === "X`"`` may be better.  Would you please try to explain in more detail what you're doing?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard that would work just as well, and I figured the answers would be straight forward.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard As to what I wish to accomplish, I wish to match an expression that has a `Head` that is a member of a specific context. To have a head, it must be a function, such as `List`. That is why my examples are littered with `x[]`, not `x`. In the case of ``_?(Context @@ # == "X`" &)``, `x[]` is passed to `PatternTest`, not `x` as `Context` expects. So, I have to strip off everything but the `Head`.