# Wildcard character within Rules

Tags: replacement, rule

Assume I have an expression caontaining n paramters `x1`...`xn` and I wish to what happens to my expression when all of my n parameters are 0. Is there a way to use Wildcard character `*` (I mean something like `x*->0`)?

Comment: at least closely related: [75294](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75294/5478)

Comment: @Kuba yep. I will flag it as duplicate.

Comment: @Kuba I forgot my own duplicate. :-(

Answer (score 3):

```
{x1, x2, x3, y1, y2} /. s_Symbol /; StringMatchQ[SymbolName[s], "x*"] -> 0
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, y1, y2}
> ```

Consider using [`Context`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Context.html) if you need more control, e.g. [Pattern match any member of a Context](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18170/121)

Comment: +1 ! or use your approach with a pattern test `{x1,x2,x3,y1,y2}/._Symbol?(StringMatchQ[SymbolName[#], "x*"] &) -> 0`